# How to retrieve info from SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml

I have an object

```
class SimpleXMLElement#3 (1) {
     public ${0} =>
     string(10) "idp:088853"
}
```

retrieved by

```
$xml = file_get_contents($xml_file); 
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElemet($xml); 
$ids = $sxml->xpath('system-identifier');
foreach( $ids as $id) {
 //....
}
```

How can I get that string out

Comment: I don't think what you shown is correct  format of `SimpleXMLElement object`. check once

Comment: Show us the code how did you get that object?

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code in there, not in the Comments.